# parsererror in JQuery: How to get the unparseable string?

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I would like to log the unparseable string from the http body when it is unparseable. How can I get to it?

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: url})
          .done(function (data)
          {
              // Do stuff
          })
          .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
          {
              if (textStatus === "parsererror")
              {
                  var rawBodyData = ?
                  console.log("Parsing failed: " + rawBodyData);
              }
          });
```

Comment: `jqXHR.responseText` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw response string can be found here: `jqXHR.responseText`